# Any callbacks available for talkback reading completion - Android

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I need to sign out the user if the app is idle for a few mins, it's applicable for accessibility enabled also. My scenario is one screen having a lot of text and talkback taking more time to complete this. I need to stop signout in this case.

Do we have any callback which will notify a view once the talkback operation is either completed or is in-progress something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of [AccessibilityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager) and [AccessibilityEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent)

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution will be to send accessibility event speaking out that user is being logged off. I am not sure if there is any callback event for this in android.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think so, talkback is remove from acces for devs to not turn them off or broke to someone who is blind and can't turn them on back.
So use:
TextToSpeach method to ini own , fully controled speach. Same as talkback use.